# Internet Explorer 10+ media queries and responsive break points

Tags: css, internet-explorer, responsive-design, media-queries

I am trying to combine an IE10+ specific media query with a max-width page break point.

I am pretty sure they can be combined but am not sure how to do it.

Here is the original IE10+ only css media query:

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
   /* IE10+ CSS styles go here */
   }
```

Here is my feeble attempt at combining them:

```
@media (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active), only screen and (max-width: 950px) {
    /* IE10+ CSS styles go here */ 
    }
```

The IE only code here works fine, however the "`max-width`" doesn't work at all.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you saying that it works in other browsers? Tell me the effect you are trying to achieve with an sample site

Comment: Your recently deleted question [is being discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365729/ask-a-question-get-the-needed-help-insult-the-helper-and-delete-the-question). You are welcome to comment or not as you wish (but, it goes without saying, keep it constructive if you do - thanks).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works if you do it like this: repeat all the parts of the media query selector.

```css
.For.IE.only {
  display: none
}

@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: active) and (max-width: 950px),
       all and (-ms-high-contrast: none) and (max-width: 950px) {
  .For.IE.only {
    display: block
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="For IE only">
  This is for IE only, and only on narrow screens
</div>
<div>
  This is for all browsers
</div>
```

Disclaimer: I don't have IE10 here, only IE11, but I'm reasonably sure it will work in IE10 as well.

Comment: Thanks Mr Lister. I will give this a try and report back.

Comment: Sorry mate time got the better of me