# How to detect an IE media query with a max-width property?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, media-queries

I have the following test to help me detect CSS modifications in IE11....

```
  @media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
    .melement {
      border:solid 1em red;
    }
  }
```

But when I attempt to check for max-width settings on this, it does not work correctly...

```
 @media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active), (max-width: 550px) {
    .melement {
      border:solid 1em red;
    }
  }
```

What am I doing wrong in my process?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```css
 @media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none) and (max-width: 550px), 
        all and (-ms-high-contrast: active) and (max-width: 550px) {
    .melement {
      border:solid 1em red;
    }
  }
```

[Answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48741259/internet-explorer-10-media-queries-and-responsive-break-points)